# CSS property to show sublist on left side

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu which looks [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wEExT/), where on hovering over "tanfa demo example" the sublist come on RHS

The problem is, that in my case the whole menu is on [extreme right](http://jsfiddle.net/wEExT/2/). I want sublist to appear on LHS.

I have tried using CSS "left: 0; top: 0;" property, but that would just show sublist on top-left corner of its parent element, where it overlaps as follows,

[image]

I want the menu to start from "left: 0; top: 0" of its parent, but then slide towards its left. I would prefer a solution through CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `right: 100%` instead of `left: 0`, which basically tells your menu that it should position its left edge to the leftmost edge of its parent. `right: 100%` should tell it to align its rightmost edge with your parent menus leftmost edge. Hope this helps!

Comment: do you want the menu to appear on the extreme lhs (eg other side of the screen) or just on the left side of the parent menu?

Comment: I wanted menu to appear just like in jsfiddle.net/wEExT/8

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, to make the sublists appear to the left of the parent set their `left` property to `-100%`.

```
#menu ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5yQx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Can try this:
set a negative margin for child (pop-up list) = 2 x the margin of parent list

i.e: Add something like this to pop up list.

```
{
    margin: 0 -300px; /* 0 denotes top and bottom margin : 0 */
}
```

PS: Not advisable though looking at your code. Will need few more changes in the code to work properly

Answer (score 1):

**left:0** means you define position to it's. So, what's the solution instead of **left:0** you can define **left:auto;**. Write like this:

```
#menu ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:auto;
right:100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

or remove **left:0** as jakee already explain.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/wEExT/9/